# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'. Anyone knows why is that?

Tags: python, sorting

Here's the code.

```
digs = (-10, 0, 7, -2, 3, 6, -8)

def sort(x):
    if x < 0:
        return False

print(sorted(digs, key=sort))
```

When launched the following error appears. Can anyone explain why?

I figured it out that I can do this:

```
def sort(x):
    return x >= 0
```

and it's gonna work fine. But I still don't get why that error shows up when comparing x and 0.

Comment: If `x` is `None` (as the error message says), then it's not a number. How can you compare something that _isn't_ a number to something that is?

Comment: It's because when `x` is greater or equal than `0`, the `if` statement isn't `True` and as so the function returns `None`, which is implicit on every function if you don't return anything.

Comment: `sorted(digs, key=lambda x: x < 0)`?

Answer (score 0):

In your first version:

```py
def sort(x):
    if x < 0:
        return False
    # but then what happens if x >= 0?
    # if the code reaches this point, the function will return None
```

In the second version of your sort function, a boolean value is always returned. This avoids the error of comparing `None` to something.

Comment: Oh I got it, tysm